# Is setting the Apache's TimeOut directive to 3 hours risky?

Tags: php, apache

In my application there are couple of PHP scripts that need about 2-3 hours to be executed by requests from the application admins. [I failed to change the Apache TimeOut directive limit only for these scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612459/can-i-increase-apaches-timeout-directive-for-specific-php-script).

So I decided to change the [Apache TimeOut](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) directive to 10800 (3 hours) "globally" and limit the PHP

```
max_execution_time = 30 // PHP.ini
```

and then change the `max_execution_time` dynamically for the specified script if needed

```
<?php
// long script
ini_set("max_execution_time", 10800);
```

Is there any risk of doing that?

Comment: I think what you are doing is a bad idea from start. HTTP is designed for request and response pattern, not request and wait ages until response. Unless a special client is used the client will timeout before the server has sent the response. The usual way to deal with long running jobs is to run in background (forked away) and if output is required collect it into a temporary file to provide it to later requests.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you very much, I will do that, looks more elegant to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has changed focus and question is now irrelevant (see comments).

Comment: Or alternatively, since the kind of job that one would access through web and that might take a long time are often reports of some kind, you might consider pre-generating, say, nightly, the kind of reports administrators are likely to require so their retrieval would take much less than three hours.

Comment: @dig thank you very much, yes I do daily reports by a cron-job. but the task in the question is not a report, it's to fill a test database with very large data for testing purposes. So it's not a daily (or predictable) task, it's done only by the testers when required (may be 1 or 2 times monthly). So the technique suggested by Steffen Ullrich looks more suitable for the situation. The admin press fill the database button and a timer with Ajax requests start to get the progress status from the server until it's 100%.

Comment: You can also send emails, we have a few report downloads that were starting to hit time limits, so we changed them to run in the background and now they send an email with links to the documents, as well as display download links on the site.